# Networking with lxc containers with local dhcp and external ipv6 double bridge problems

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6, bridge, lxc

I want to use both ipv6 externally on all my containers, and ipv4 external only on the hosts. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. For ipv4 on the container I use the DHCP that came with the lxc installation.

I got the setup working, but I'm not sure this is correct. Could you guys shed some
light on it?

On my container host I use:

```
 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback
    address 127.0.0.1
    netmask 255.0.0.0

 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet manual

 auto br-lxc
 iface br-lxc inet static
    address ipv4
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway ipv4 gw
    bridge_ports eth0

 iface br-lxc inet6 static
    address exte:rnal::ipv6
    netmask 48
    gateway exte:rnal:ipv6:gw
```

In my container configuration:

```
 lxc.network.type= veth
 lxc.network.flags= up
 lxc.network.link= br-lxc
 lxc.network.hwaddr= random-mac
 lxc.network.name = eth0

 lxc.network.type=veth
 lxc.network.link=br-lxc-1 
 lxc.network.flags=up
 lxc.network.hwaddr= random-mac
 lxc.network.name = eth1
```

And in my container(s) I use:

```
 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback

 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet6 static
    address ipv6
    netmask 48
    gateway ipv6 gw

 auto eth1
 iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

And I get in the container:

```
 $ip a|grep inet
    inet6 externalipv6:33/48 scope global
    inet6 internalipv6::78/64 scope link
    inet 10.0.3.52/24 brd 10.0.3.255 scope global eth1
    inet6 internalipv6::28/64 scope link
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
```

- Is this correct?
- Is there a better way to bridge the ipv6 to the containers?

When I need to restart the network I get:

```
$ /etc/init.d/networking restart

* Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces
* Reconfiguring network interfaces...   

Device "br-lxc" does not exist.
```